# Azure Functions - Can't deploy functions using VSCODE extension - Deploy hangs forever at uploading zip package to storage container

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I have read a lot of articles, docs but can't deploy a function to Microsoft Azure functions app using vscode azure functions extension. It hangs forever at **Uploading zip package to storage container...** and it didn't give any useful details.

I have tried to reinstall the extension, create new function apps but the error is still hapenning.

Package versions:

```
NodeJS 14
azure/functions": "^1.2.3",
azure-functions-core-tools": "3",
```

Answer (score 2):

same issue , I also have searched a lot. creation of func app is so fast but when it comes to deploy , hangs in creation zip package for ever.

update:
After several times trying , I realized the zip package size  is too big ( around 3G) ! so it seems it is packaging everything in the function app folder and for me this was this the reason of endless "creating zip package" . I just excluded unnecessary folder and files in .funcignore then the deployment is done pretty quick under (2 min). hope it also works for others.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a common problem. I just gave up and switched to serverless framework

Comment: Can I ask how you determined which folders to add to the .funcignore? I have a large node-module/aws-sdk that I'm unsure whether it is needed or not in the deployment package